# Get the username and the process ID of a process in bash

Tags: bash, ps

I am writing a bash script where I need to find out the userID of a process. For an example let the process be bash itself.

I tried `ps aux | grep ba[s]h` but the following was returned:

```
1000      2745  0.0  0.1  28360  5440 pts/1    Ss   10:11   0:01 bash
```

I see the userID 1000 displayed, but I want the username.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/370699/204979

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can happen if the username is longer than 8 characters **(OR)** id has no name. But, If you want the username in the `ps` output then try this,

```
ps -eo uname:20,pid,pcpu,pmem,sz,tty,stat,time,cmd | grep '[b]ash'
```

Comment: thanks, when i ran this command i get `mylongusername          11546  0.0  0.0  3398 pts/4    S+   00:00:00 grep --color=auto process` why this is returning this process always. i tried killing it, but than i got the response that `exe: kill (11546) : No such process`.

Comment: @i_m_optional, You try this: `ps -eo pid,cmd | grep -v grep`

Comment: Ohh Yes, i got it now. Stupid me :p

Answer (score 1):

You can parse out the `/proc` entry if you are on Linux and if you just need a numeric pid (or are OK with it). Here is an example for the `mysqld` process:

```
grep -e '^Uid:' /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/status | cut -f 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way I found so far ( $PID - ID of the process inspected):

```
ps -p $PID -o euid=
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for gedit process

```
grep -w Pid /proc/$(pidof gedit)/status | cut -f 2
```